# Change the "shop base" slug for a certain WooCommerce product (ID)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting, product, permalinks

I am looking to change/rewrite a certain product's url/permalink. I have the product ID, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

**Example:**
I am using
`/courses/course1` as the shop base (as it was originally just courses that were sold).

Now I'm looking to create a product with the url of `/course-materials/book1`.

I assume there is a php script in functions.php to override the set woocommerce shop base, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If both courses and coursers-materials are products categories, you could change permalink format (WordPress > Settings > Permalinks) to "Shop base with category" option, generating permalinks like /shop/product-category/sample-product/.

Comment: Hi @Delonix, and thank you for your answer. `/courses` is my shop base now. So I want to avoid changing all excisting links. It doesn't feel right to have `/shop` as it's courses that isn't connected with WooCommerce.

Comment: @Blomshit, the `/shop`  in the example refers to woocommerce base page (WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products -> Shop page). As I said, if `courses` is already a category, there will be no changes to the existing links.

Comment: sorry, I see that I've written the wrong base. I am now having `/our-courses/` as shop base, so a course would have the url of `/our-courses/course1`. So my issue is to avoid `/our-courses/course-materials/book1`

Comment: Could you show us how it is set up your "Product permalinks", at WordPress -> Settings -> Permalinks?
It seems strange to me that you have  "Shop base" (/our-courses/course1) and "Shop base with category" permalink formats (/our-courses/course-materials/book1), at same time.